# converting date into timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

I have date like this `25. 02. 2014 18:48:21` and I'm trying to convert it into timestamp

```
var someDate = '25. 02. 2014 18:48:21';
var timestamp = new Date(someDate).getTime();
```

but it's returning NaN since I moved files to a new domain, what can be a problem?

Comment: To a new domain? JavaScript has nothing to do with your server. It is your date, that is not in the right format.

Comment: …to a new server? Did the files get corrupted on the way?

Comment: yes I know, but this format used to work on old domain. What should be  the right format?

Comment: Is your old domain on a server in Czech Republic or Croatia where this date format is used?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'25. 02. 2014 18:48:21'` is not a valid date format. You'll have to convert it with regex first, like that:

```
var someDate = '25. 02. 2014 18:48:21';
var converted = someDate.replace(/^(\d{2}\. )(\d{2}\. )(\d{4})/, '$3. $2$1');
// converted is in format: YYYY. MM. DD.
var timestamp = new Date(converted).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this within the console, creating a new date with that variable gives me `Invalid Date`.  Trying switching around the 25. and 02. like so:

```
var someDate = '02. 25. 2014 18:48:21';
var timestamp = new Date(someDate).getTime(); // 1393372101000
```

The format should be "Month, Day, Year, Time".

Answer (score 0):

Switching month and day will work. I also removed the dots.

```
var date = "25. 02. 2014 18:48:21";
new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\. (\d{2})\./, '$2 $1'))
// Tue Feb 25 2014 18:48:21 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below (if your string has always same format)

```
var someDate = '25. 02. 2014 18:48:21';
var arr = someDate.split(' ');
var time = arr[3].split(':');
var timeStamp = new Date(arr[2],arr[1].split('.')[0],arr[0].split('.')[0],time [0],time[1],time[2]).getTime();
```

It uses javascript date object constructor

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);
```

which works across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertSomeDate(str){
    var d= str.match(/\d+/g), 
    dA= [d[2], '-', d[1], '-', d[0], 'T', d[3], ':', d[4], ':', d[5], 'Z'].join('');
    return +new Date(dA)
}

var someDate= '25. 02. 2014 18:48:21';
convertSomeDate(someDate)
```

/*  returned value: (Number)
1393354101000
*/